# How to throw a user-defined exception in a ksh script

Tags: exception, ksh

```
CHECK_FTP=`cat ftp_test.txt | grep 'Login incorrect.'`
if [ -n "$CHECK_FTP" ]; then
" login is incorrect, please correct the password/username "
cd unable_to_connect_to_remote_server
```

In the above code I need to raise a user defined exception, please note I cannot use the command exit, since it exits the script but it does not fail the script.

Comment: `exit 1` will indicate that your script had a failure. That is essentially your only option. Good luck.

Comment: yeah. correct i was missing 1 in exit command. if i used normal just exit. it complete's the script rather than failing it. issue is resolved now.